# redis server uses high cpu

Tags: redis, centos

I've inherited a custom built webpage which uses redis server and i noticed that in  every 3-5 minutes redis server peaks and uses 100% cpu for maybe 2-3 minutes.

Anyone have any ideas or clues on what i can do to optimize this?

```
Log file:
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:22:44.060 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:22:44.356 * Background saving started by pid 16081
16081:C 23 Apr 2019 18:25:03.575 * DB saved on disk
16081:C 23 Apr 2019 18:25:03.783 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:25:04.174 * Background saving terminated with success
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:30:05.089 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:30:05.396 * Background saving started by pid 16984
16984:C 23 Apr 2019 18:32:26.841 * DB saved on disk
16984:C 23 Apr 2019 18:32:27.126 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:32:27.523 * Background saving terminated with success
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:47:28.032 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:47:28.334 * Background saving started by pid 18748
18748:C 23 Apr 2019 18:49:53.540 * DB saved on disk
18748:C 23 Apr 2019 18:49:53.744 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:49:54.157 * Background saving terminated with success
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:54:55.023 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:54:55.328 * Background saving started by pid 19422
19422:C 23 Apr 2019 18:57:18.455 * DB saved on disk
19422:C 23 Apr 2019 18:57:18.592 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
2276:M 23 Apr 2019 18:57:18.823 * Background saving terminated with success
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how Redis is. The backup process involves heavy amounts of compression which will, for a time, pin a single core.

You can switch to using the AOF (append-only-file) exclusively, but that does require periodic pruning and compression as well, it's just less frequent and demanding.

[The manual](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) has some specifics, including this caveat:

> There are many users using AOF alone, but we discourage it since to have an RDB snapshot from time to time is a great idea for doing database backups, for faster restarts, and in the event of bugs in the AOF engine.